# how does copyright work for performer and singing cover tunes and or singing a translation i worote

Tags: copyright, music, recording, translation

I have  translated a few  songs  from the 19 century and early 20th century.  i sing as well and would  like to perform them and  post  them on my youtube page and or record them .

One one of the songs is BUtterfield's lullaby  also known as TAPS.

Because TAPS's  melody is from mid 19th century 1836 -39   and the  lyrics  is considered a children nursery rhyme ...  I am thinking  that it is okay to  sing and record and share with public and post or sell  my translated version.

I don't realize i may need  to share profit .

I would  also like to protect my translated version somehow. How do I do that?

Comment: What's your jurisdiction? United States?

Answer (score 1):

Any song or other music composed and published in the 1830s is very likely to be in the public domain by now, although it will depend on the exact laws in your country, and, in some countries, on the year in which the author/composer died. In the US if it was published before 1924 it will be in the public domain now, but the rule is different in different countries.

Assuming that the work is in the public domain, you may freely create translations, or modified versions, and perform them. You may sell those performances, or distribute them free of charge.

In all countries which adhere to the Berne Copyright Convention, which meals all but a handful of countries in the world, your work is fully protected the moment you write4 it down, or otherwise "fix it in a tangible medium". (Computer files count.)

In the US you may choose to register a copyright. This gives you additional rights should you sue for infringement later. It also provides evidence of your copyrighted work. However, there is a fee. Some other countries have similar procedures. Each country is different, and registration in one does not provide registration in any other. But in all of the Berne countries, registration is optional.

Comment: Yes David I am working on a translation of a Particular song  written in the 19th century so i know  it is  of public Domain.  Now  the lyrics  I am not  sure about , However  I do know  that  there are NO OFFICIAL lyrics to the songs. Or  now  the  lullaby  is a Children's nursery rhyme so I think  i can use  those  freely as well yes?  However  being there are so many variations on the lyrics  should I see which are  free to use  and which are not.. obviously,  Or  should i contact the owner if possible and see if he  would mind  the translation and then we share profits. I am in US

Comment: r protection for 90 years?

Comment: You have a lot of minor spelling errors in your recent posts

Comment: @Mara L. Bachicha There are countries with life +80 and I think life +100 copyright terms, and if the composer was young when the work was created and lived to an old age, protection could in theory last for up to say 150 years or more.

Comment: @Dalke M: Thanks, I will try to fix them

Comment: @Mara L. Bachicha protection does not depend on words being '"official" nor does "nursery rhyme" = not protected.

Comment: On the other hand, lots of nursery rhymes are nonsense, so you can't really translate them, but have to create something totally new.

Comment: "In the US if it was published before 1924" - A clearer phrasing would be "If it was **published in the US before 1924**." If it was published outside the US, in noncompliance with US formalities, and you happen to be in the Ninth Circuit, it's [a bit of a mess](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikilegal/The_9th_Circuit_and_Works_Published_Without_Formalities).

Comment: True, but I expect that 9th circuit ruling to be overturned eventually, none of the other circuits follow it. Otherwise, under US law, anything published before 1924, in the uS or out, is PD.